# Cannot access settings of a wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, wp-admin, woocommerce-currency-switcher

I have a wordpress project set up locally in my computer and i'm trying to add a new plugin to it.

I have installed `WooCommerce Currency Switcher by WooBeWoo` plugin and activated it. When i try to go to the settings page of this plugin i get this error

```
Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.
```

I have searched for a answer but could not find a working solution.

I have tried the following.

I have changed `wp_capability` in `wp_usermeta` table to `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}`

But still could not get it to work. I can access settings of already existed plugins and this is a new plugin i have added.

The plugin used : https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-currency-switcher/

Comment: Could it be that the plugin is broken?

Comment: The plugin i used is this https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-currency-switcher/ i referred the FAQ, it seems this is working fine. I dont understand why i cannot get this to work.

Comment: Is it a network site? Multi site?